# How do combine a dictionary with a function?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to set each letter of the alphabet to a numeric value: a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, etc.

I created a dictionary to set each letter to a value. I created a function that takes in a word and finds the total value of its letters. How do I access my created dictionary within my function?

```
Console.WriteLine("YOUR NAME VALUE IS: " + hashFunction("b"));//I want the output to be 2 (b = 2) in this case.

int hashFunction(string name)
{
    int totalSum = 0;
    Char [] characters = name.ToCharArray();
    for (int letterIndex = 0; letterIndex < characters.Length; letterIndex++)
    {
        totalSum += Convert.ToInt32(characters[letterIndex]);
    }

    return totalSum;
}

Dictionary<char, int> charValues = new Dictionary<char, int>();

        charValues.Add('a', 1);
        charValues.Add('b', 2);
        charValues.Add('c', 3);
        charValues.Add('d', 4);
        charValues.Add('e', 5);
        //etc etc etc
    }
```

Comment: You're already accessing it in your function: `charValues.Add` accesses the dictionary.

Comment: But why though, since you can; `character - 'a' + 1`

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar For example, when I try to call the function: Console.WriteLine("YOUR NAME VALUE IS: " + hashFunction("b"));

Im expecting b to be a value of 2. However, the result ends up being 98 (which has to do with ASCII I believe). I don't think the function is accessing the dictionary keys/values. I'm new to dictionaries if you couldnt tell lol

Comment: `var totalSum = name.Sum(c => c - 'a' + 1);`

Comment: `totalSum += charValues[characters[letterIndex]];`

Answer (score 1):

Since letters `a..z` within ASCII table are *consequent* we can compute letter index as

```
letter - 'a' + 1
```

without elaborated mappig based on dictionary. Then we can use *Linq* to find the `Sum`:

```
using System.Linq;

...

// static : we don't want "this" within the method
static int hashFunction(string name) => name
  .Where(c => c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
  .Sum(c => c - 'a' + 1);
```

**Edit:** if you *insist* on dictionary based solution, you can put it like this:

```
using System.Linq;
  
... 

static IReadOnlyDictionary<char, int> charValues = Enumerable
  .Range('a', 'z' - 'a' + 1)
  .ToDictionary(letter => (char)letter, letter - 'a' + 1);

int hashFunction(string name)
{
  int totalSum = 0;

  foreach (char c in name) 
    if (charValues.TryGetValue(c, out int v))
      totalSum += v;    

  return totalSum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a dictionary?

```
IEnumerable<int> MapCharsToInts( IEnumerable<char> chars )
{
  foreach ( char ch in chars.Map( c => Char.ToLower(c) )
  {
    int v = 1 + ch - 'a' ;
    yield v >= 1 && v <= 26 ? v : 0 ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I access my created dictionary within my function?

by the name of the variable. You use the `[  ]` brakets like in an array, but you pass a key values as parameter into it. In your case one of the chars that you retrieve from your char array. You can actually use the string directly to access the chars, since it is a char array under the hood:

```
int hashFunction(string name)
{
    int totalSum = 0;
    for (int letterIndex = 0; letterIndex < name.Length; letterIndex++)
    {
        char theKey = name[letterIndex]; 
        totalSum += charValues[theKey];
    }

    return totalSum;
}
```

the dictionary will then return the appropriate integer, or it will throw an exception if it does not find any match.

The most important part is that the dictionary has to be declared as field or property on class level! not a local variable in some other method.